# What is the best way to break execution / return to caller of anonymous functions (Kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

I would like to use the `return` statement as a way to break the execution of a function like:

```
fun divide(i1: Int, i2: Int) {
    if (i2 == 0) return
    print(i1 / i2)
}
```

The function I am using looks like this:

```
val messageCreateEvent: suspend MessageCreateEvent.() -> Unit = {
        run work@ {
            val submissionID = URLReviewer.getSubmissionID(message.content) ?: return@work
            // some code
        }
}
```

(I know, the same functionality could be achieved with only an if-statement.)

Currently, I am specifying the label `@work` to return to.

Is there a better way to return to the function caller / break the execution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Theoretically you could also simply make `messageCreateEvent` a real function. And then pass it as `highOrder(::messageCreateEvent)` instead of `highOrder(messageCreateEvent)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could more simply be written:

```
suspend fun messageCreateEvent(event: MessageCreateEvent) = with(event) {
    val submissionID = URLReviewer.getSubmissionID(message.content) ?: return
    // some code
}
```

You can get a reference to any function using `::` if you need to pass it as a parameter to something.

Just FYI, you can also return from an inline lambda by naming the function that it's passed to:

```
val messageCreateEvent: suspend MessageCreateEvent.() -> Unit = {
        run {
            val submissionID = URLReviewer.getSubmissionID(message.content) ?: return@run
            // some code
        }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much!
I did never use the `with` function, read a little into it and it seems like the perfect solution for my problem.
`inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R` - 
`Calls the specified function block with the given receiver as its receiver and returns its result.`

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but found an answer to my question:

```
val messageCreateEvent: suspend MessageCreateEvent.() -> Unit = work@ {
        val submissionID = URLReviewer.getSubmissionID(message.content) ?: return@work
        // some code
}
```

You can simply label the whole block of the anonymous function.
Like that you don't need a run-block as I used it before.

This solution whilst not perfect will do it for me.